# SQL Ordenamiento por ID y valor en 2 tablas distintas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Actualmente necesito realizar una consulta a 2 tablas donde los datos tienen varias columnas iguales. El problema radica en que el ordenamiento debe realizarse basado en como esta estructurado el orden de la tabla A pero al mismo tiempo tomando el valor de la columna ValorOrden de la tabla B de manera consecutiva y ascedente. Datos de ejemplo:

```
declare @table1 table(idMetadata int, Orden int identity)
insert into @table1 values (15)
insert into @table1 values (16)
insert into @table1 values (17)

select * from @table1

declare @table2 table(idDet int, idEnc int, IDMetadata int, OrderValue int, Orden int null)
insert into @table2 values (185441, 22008, 15, 7, null)
insert into @table2 values (187777, 22269, 15, 7, null)
insert into @table2 values (211259, 24925, 15, 7, null)
insert into @table2 values (251476, 29431, 15, 4, null)
insert into @table2 values (185442, 22008, 16, 6, null)
insert into @table2 values (187778, 22269, 16, 6, null)
insert into @table2 values (211260, 24925, 16, 6, null)
insert into @table2 values (251477, 29431, 16, 5, null)
insert into @table2 values (251478, 29431, 17, 6, null)

update t2
set t2.Orden = t1.Orden
from @table1 t1
inner join @table2 t2
on t1.idMetadata = t2.IDMetadata
```

Pude realizar el siguiente select:

```
SELECT distinct A.*
FROM @table2 B1 
LEFT join @table2 A
on A.idMetadata in (select a.idMetadata from @table1 A)
AND A.Orden in (select a.Orden from @table1 A)
where b1.OrderValue > a.OrderValue
```

Pero me muestra el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es crear una consulta generica que muestre unicamente aquellos registros de la tabla B que tienen la misma metadata y orden de la tabla A, que tienen internamente en la tabla B el mismo "idEnc" pero cuyo campo "OrderValue" sea consecutivo y ascendente a como lo muestra la siguiente imagen con los campos marcados en amarillo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos

Comment: no entiendo muy bien, tu tienes dos tablas A(isMetadata, Orden) y B(idEnc, IDMetadata, ValorOrden) si haces un join va a hacer igualando B.IDMetadata con A.idMetadata con eso los valores que puedes mostrar seria una tabla C(idEnc, (el campo igualado) IDMetadata , ValorOrden y Orden) de esos campos cual es el que deseas ordenar?

Comment: Si puedes añadir a tu pregunta un ejemplo del resultado esperado, sería mucho mejor.

Comment: Listo, ya reformulé la pregunta.

Comment: Los primeros tres registros No deberían aparecer? y si los últimos 3, siempre y cuando el orden de A sean consecutivos y el orden de B también lo sean?. Intento entender mejor

Comment: @ArielOctavioD'Alfeo Correcto, los primeros 3 registros no deberían aparecer siempre y cuando ambas tablas tengan el mismo IdMetadata, Mismo campo "Orden" y el campo "OrderValue" de la tabla B para los registros que cumplen la anterior condición sean consecutivos y ascendentes, ejemplo (3, 4, 5, 6, 7, etc.).

Comment: Hola @Adrian87, Creo que el planteamiento de la pregunta es poco claro. Hablas de las tablas A y B, pero tu script tiene `@Table1` y `@Table2` y la condición está poco clara (y la consulta que has hecho ayuda menos a aclararla). Además, la clausula update que haces sobre los campos, ayuda aún menos a entender la idea. Creo que es mejor que muestres los datos tal como están (o como deben quedar después de cualquier update), y luego, trates de expresar la condición de manera clara. Por otro lado, en el conjunto de resultados de ejemplo, muestra solo los datos que SI te interesa obtener.

Answer (score 1):

Tú código es correcto, solo al ultimo debes hacerle una consulta dándole un order a todos tus campos

```
declare @table1 table(idMetadata int, Orden int identity)
insert into @table1 values (15)
insert into @table1 values (16)
insert into @table1 values (17)

select * from @table1

declare @table2 table(idDet int, idEnc int, IDMetadata int, OrderValue int, Orden int null)
insert into @table2 values (185441, 22008, 15, 7, null)
insert into @table2 values (187777, 22269, 15, 7, null)
insert into @table2 values (211259, 24925, 15, 7, null)
insert into @table2 values (251476, 29431, 15, 4, null)
insert into @table2 values (185442, 22008, 16, 6, null)
insert into @table2 values (187778, 22269, 16, 6, null)
insert into @table2 values (211260, 24925, 16, 6, null)
insert into @table2 values (251477, 29431, 16, 5, null)
insert into @table2 values (251478, 29431, 17, 6, null)

--select * from @table2
update t2
set t2.Orden = t1.Orden
from @table1 t1
inner join @table2 t2
on t1.idMetadata = t2.IDMetadata
select * from @table2 order by idEnc asc,IDMetadata asc,ordervalue asc,orden asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta es mi opción

[1] Como te interesa solo los campos de A, tanto te importa hacer distinct A.* como distinct B1.*

[2] Entonces, en la tercera linea, te puedes traer son los registros duplicados. Debería ser algo así JOIN (select idDet distinct from @table2 group by idDet having count(*)>1) A. Al sacarle el LEFT lo que tenemos en este punto es:

SELECT distinct B1.*

FROM @table2 B1

JOIN (select idDet distinct from @table2 group by idDet having count(*)>1) A

Ahora ya tienes los campos únicos de la tabla 2. Solo falta hacer el join hacia la primera tabla

LEFT JOIN @table1 B ON B.ORDER = B1.OrderValue

Ahora ya sería cuestión de añadir el orden deseado